# Vote to close does not appear, but can not close the question for the moment

Tags: discussion

I remembered I voted to close [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884509/xamarin-android-show-button-or-linearlayout-in-another-activity) question few days ago. Now that I came back to it, I am surprised to see my vote does not show. So I tried to vote to close it again, but then it says I have already done that and I can vote to close it again on August 1st:

[image]

This is the first time that happens to me and it sounds weird to me. Can you explain me what is all this about?

Comment: close votes age away now, but, being unable to recast it seems odd. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away

Comment: So my vote aged away? ... I did not know this results in this behavior. Thank you for the info.

Comment: @KevinB You have to wait 14 days after it ages away before you can vote again. The ability was added quite a while ago, but can only be done on votes that aged away (not retracted or used votes).

Comment: @animuson That is the answer. Don't abuse comments :P